# Normal scroll with fullpage scroll in the one website

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, pagepiling.js

Please help me. I am developing a website. On it, according to the designer's idea, it should have 5 sections, 3 sections are already ready. But on all sections except "about" and "jobs" there should be a normal scroll, and on sections "about" and "jobs" full-screen scroll. And in section "jobs" it should be a vertical slider that slides secions "fieldsOfOperation", "expertise", "services". I tried using the fullpage.js plugin, but it makes the whole site full screen, the same situation with the pagepiling.js plugin.

```
<body>
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <!-- some code here -->
        </header>
   <main>
        <div class="about">
            <div class="about__text-one">We are a UAE-based EPC company proved itself remarkably effective
                in
                engineering,
                procurement and construction that
                supports the Oil&Gas, Energy and Chemistry industries in the Middle East and Central Asia.
            </div>
            <img class="about__img" src="./img/about__img.svg" alt="Map">
            <div class="about__text-two">Since establishment in 2014, FUTURIS has gained trust and has been
                registered
                by the leading Oil&Gas Companies operating
                in Central Asia and strives to contribute to the successes of the Clients' projects.</div>
        </div>
            <div class="jobs">
            <section class="fieldsOfOperation">
                <h2 class="fieldsOfOperation__title">Fields of Operation</h2>
                <div class="fieldOfOperation__texts">
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Oil & Gas</span>
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Chemistry</span>
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Energy</span>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="expertise">
                <h2 class="expertise__title">Expertise</h2>
                <div class="expertise__texts">
                    <span class="expertise__text">Drilling Equipment</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Instrumentation & Electrical</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Valves & Pumps</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Mechanical Equipment & Rotating Machinery</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Process Equipment</span>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="services">
                <h2 class="services__title">Services</h2>
                <div class="services__texts">
                    <span class="services__text">Automation & Control</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Commissioning & Decommissioning</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Welding</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Isolation</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Operational Assurance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Destructive Testing</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Hydrotesting</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Intelligent Pigging</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Pipeline Equipment Maintenance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Flow Assurance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Construction</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Wiring</span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

As I said above, I tried to use plugins such as fullpage.js and pagepilling.js. But i got stucked with this problem. Please help, how can I combine normal scrolling with full-screen scrolling on one site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrollable sections for sections with content larger than he viewport by using the `scrollOverflow` option in fullPage.js.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/ExmwGGY).

More on [the fullPage.js documentation](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/docs/#:%7E:text=such%20as%20color.-,scrollOverflow)

Comment: But how I can remove the smooth transition from section1 to section2, like there is no fullpage plugin?

Comment: You want normal scroll? Then use `autoScrolling: false`. 
Or if you just want to move from one secvction to another without any scrolling effect, reduce the speed to 0. `scrollingSpeed: 0`.